# a board game server with using combination of tcp,udp good idea?

Tags: performance, tcp, udp, netty

I am coding board game server using Netty. Using TCP at every part of the game. But I am having issues most of the time. Even though have posted several questions, tried many configuration parameters, I am still having issues (latency and un-expected disconnect issues at most)

My idea is, using TCP while visitors playing the game. Other than this, if you are exploring rooms, checking tables, looking for friends etc. will use UDP instead. Can I expect performance increase ?

Server: JAVA, Linux
Client: Adobe Flash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because in the end you will have to account for those udp messages not getting where they are going.  If I *know* my friend is playing and when I search for friends he doesn't come up, I'll just run the search over again.

If you truly have too much traffic (which seems bizarre for a board game server) you can always isolate different functionality to different servers.  For example, one server could be dedicated to chat, another to lobbies, and another 3 to running games.

Comment: load is not that much to be honest. 6500 concurrent users. no problem with server. but still having issues like http://stackoverflow.com/q/8735731/378737 .

Answer (score 0):

On a related note. Here is a [netty game server](https://github.com/menacher/java-game-server) which has an as3 client in the same repo. It also support UDP but you need to use Java/C other language client, not flash.